# Materials have suddenly stopped working

Tags: rendering, materials, error

I have recently gone back to a project I have been working on and the materials I have previously used no longer render properly.

When I select the materials preview in the viewport I am treated to a weird disco light show.
[image: matpreview]

Rendering the image from the camera also no longer works.
[image]

I have tried recreating the textures from scratch but this doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not have an AMD GPU, instead of downgrading your drivers, try to update them to the latest ones available